# Concat not working - The underlying array is null

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to Concat the two array IEnumerable lists and in result view it says `The underlying array is null`.

```
IEnumerable<ObjectToConcat> result = new ArraySegment<ObjectToConcat>();

var listA = new List<ObjectToConcat>();

var a = new ObjectToConcat 
{OfficialId = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "A Object"};
listA.Add(a);

var b = new ObjectToConcat 
{OfficialId = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "B Object"};
listA.Add(b);

// Error here is result view
result = result.Concat(listA);

var c = new ObjectToConcat 
{OfficialId = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "C Object"};
listB.Add(c);

// Error here is result view
result = result.Concat(listB);
```

Can anyone please suggest me what is wrong with my code. Or `Concat` does not work with `List`?

Comment: With the code example provided it's not immediately clear why you don't just add to `result` directly. What is it you're **really** trying to do?

Comment: The source of problem is `ArraySegment`. Try to use `List` for instance.

Comment: @neoistheone thanks for pointing out. I have updated the code before your comment. Actually I am merging more than one list into result. this is just an example code to keep it simple. in Actual code, I am trying to use Concat inside foreach.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov I have tried list as well, it throws an error saying `Unable to cast object of type '<ConcatIterator>d__71`1[ConcatTest.ObjectToConcat]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConcatTest.ObjectToConcat]'.`

Comment: It's hard to guess what's wrong. Just show to actual code you have problem with or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). The snippet you've presented lacks the definition of `listB` for example.

Comment: Since ArraySegment doesn't appear to [have an empty constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f47hffe.aspx), I'm surprised that even compiles.

Comment: @MattBurland it does compile

Comment: @MattBurland ArraySegment is struct, so it compiles. )))

Comment: @Scorpion: Well, there's your problem then. It's supposed to have an array passed to it, which you didn't do. Hence the *absolutely accurate* error message: `The underlying array is null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that this code:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectToConcat> result = new ArraySegment<ObjectToConcat>();
```

is an attempt to make an empty enumerable.  You can do this more effectively and clearly by writing:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectToConcat> result = Enumerable.Empty<ObjectToConcat>();
```

That said, chaining a lot of `Concat` calls probably isn't the most effective, performance wise, if there are a lot of sub-lists.  It's probably going to perform a bit better if you create a `List<IEnumerable<ObjecToConcat>> allLists`, add all of the sub-lists to that list, and then at the end you can write:

```
result = allLists.SelectMany(x => x);
```

to flatten it down to just a list of items.

Answer (score 1):

you can have list of `ObjectToConcat` like below and add items to it using addrange method

```
List<ObjectToConcat> result = new List<ObjectToConcat>();

result.AddRange(listA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectToConcat> result = 
       new ArraySegment<ObjectToConcat>(new ObjectToConcat[0]).Array;
```

Comment: There's no real point for using an `ArraySegment` here.  The zero item array can make an empty enumerable just fine on it's own.